# I want a T-SQL procedure or sql query to perform the following action:

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, top-n

I have a table with these rows:

```
City     | Day
NEWYORK  | MON
NEWYORK  | MON
NEWYORK  | MON
NEWYORK  | TUE
CHICAGO  | MON
CHICAGO  | MON
```

I need to write a query to add column `Occurrence` to the result using data from Columns `City` and `Day`:

```
City     | Day    | Occurrence
NEWYORK  | MON    |   1
NEWYORK  | MON    |   2
NEWYORK  | MON    |   3
NEWYORK  | TUE    |   1
CHICAGO  | MON    |   1
CHICAGO  | MON    |   2
```

EG: For `NEWYORK` if `MON` occurs 1st then `Occurrence`=1, if `MON` occurs twice then corresponding `Occurrence`=2 and so on.

Comment: column names are City,Day and Occurence. 6 rows and 3 columns

Comment: MySQL, SQL-Server or pl/SQL? Please add only relevant tags

Comment: Jens please help me

Comment: How i should? I do not know which dbms op is using

Comment: simple sql or pl/sql any method just help me solve this

Comment: i am using sql server management studio

Comment: All the SQL dialects are very Different. Also so How your Result should looks like

Comment: actually the 3rd column is not present in the table i need to calculate it using 1st two columns. So thats my result

Answer (score 2):

The `row_number` window function should do exactly what you're looking for:

```
SELECT [city], [day], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [city], [day] ORDER BY 1) AS [occurence]
FROM   my_table;
```